# Meteor publication error detection

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm using Meteor and angularJS 2 in web application. Please look at the below publication function.

```
Meteor.publish('abc', function () {
 // For throwing the meteor error according to the condition
 if(!this.userId) throw new Meteor.Error(403,'UnAuthorized error');
 // Returning the collection.
 return collection.find(); 
});
```

Now while subscribe the above publication from angularjs2, I'm using following code:-

// Var declarations

```
this.meteorSubscription = MeteorObservable.subscribe("abc").subscribe(() => {
    // Here subscribe data ready, so I called to other method.
});
```

The problem is here is that, how could i catch publication function error

> 'throw new Meteor.Error(403,'UnAuthorized error')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second argument of subscribe method is error callback, So you can write some condition here.

```
this.meteorSubscription = MeteorObservable.subscribe("abc").subscribe(() =>{
    // Here subscribe data ready, so I called to other method.
},error => console.log('error',error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the callback.

```
this.meteorSubscription = MeteorObservable.subscribe("abc").subscribe((err) => {
     if (err){
        console.log(err);
     }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks. but how can I track error ? I've read about onReady and onStop function. onReady called successfully when I called any functin inside subscribe().

Comment: did my answer work? the issue is in the publication, so add a `console.log(this.userId)` before throwing the error.

Comment: No, No issue in publication function. Assume is there any error caught, and i want to throw that error. not how can i catch the error on client side in subscription function.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question, here's an update.